# Jquery Plugin easySlider 1.7 - How can be created cross-fade effect in easySlider?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, easyslider

Jquery Plugin [easySlider 1.7](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) - How can be created cross-fade effect in easySlider?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This plug-in is built for sliding transitions only, so doing a cross-fade would require modifying the plug-in (ill advised) or finding a new plug-in.  I recently discussed a way you can implement cross-fading by hand-coded jQuery in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729846/jquery-simultaneously-fadein-and-fadeout/4730663#4730663).  I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, Which plugin can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using easySlider1.7 then you can modify this easily.

```
Replace `marginTop: p` with ` opacity: 1` and `opacity: 0` at lines 133 and 169.
```

Then the slider will fade when vertical option is set to false. Or you can add your own option, just add two if sentences on those lines. Then you can switch between all options (vertical, horizontal, crossfade) on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the easyslider code with this plugin code.

http://bogojoker.com/easySlide/

(Get the code from the link 'Link to js file' down the bottom under 'Modified js file').

Then follow the examples on the website to create your desired fade. Really easy.

Answer (score 0):

look for this line

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                    p = (t*w*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { marginLeft: p }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:speed, complete:adjust }
                    );              
                }
```

and change it for

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                    p = (t*w*-1);
                    $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { opacity: 0 }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:'slow', complete:adjust }
                    );  

                }
```

then look for this line

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
            }
```

and change it for

```
if(!options.vertical) {
                $("ul",obj).css("margin-left",(t*w*-1));
                $("ul",obj).animate(
                        { opacity: 1 }, 
                        { queue:false, duration:'slow'}
                    );  
            }
```

I hope this help you