# Fadein Fadeout for this gallery

Tags: jquery, gallery, fadein, fadeout

I've done a gallery with thumbs and main photo this is the code :

```
.click(function () {
    $('span.arrow').remove();  
    $('#frtitle').html($(this).find("img").attr('title'));
    $('#desc').html($(this).find("img").attr('alt'));         
    $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
    $('#slideshow-main li').removeClass('active').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);        
    $('#slideshow-main li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);    
    return false;
});
```

But The fadein and out doesn't work well it shows the background and fadeout fast

You can take a look at the main gallery [here](http://misslebanon2010.com/urbana/new/index.php).

Comment: take a look at this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729846/jquery-simultaneously-fadein-and-fadeout) - it seems you're running into some queue issues

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the fadeIn starts before the fadeOut is done.

You can pass a callback-function to the `animate()`-function.
It gets called, when the animation is done :)

```
$('#slideshow-main li').removeClass('active').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, function() {        
    $('#slideshow-main li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the images do not even fade out. The images seem to be instantly disappearing to a white background, and then the next image gradually fades in. I am guessing that you are setting `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` when you remove the `active` class.

I think what you're looking for is something closer to this (in addition to what Stefan Fandler mentioned), after changing the `active` class properties or assigning it later on:

```
$('#slideshow-main li').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);
```

...and then not have the image disappearing through the class.

Another option is to use [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) to change the opacity. Something along the lines of:

```
transition: opacity 1.5s linear;      
-webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s linear;  
-moz-transition: opacity 1.5s linear;  
-o-transition: opacity 1.5s linear;  
-ms-transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
```

This option does not require the use of JavaScript for fading in and out.